# Image doesn't fill the square

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want the image to fill all the box, i don't want to have those borders between them. Image doesn't fill all the square box. I tried everything but nothing works.If someone can help me i would really appreciate it, the problem is when i rotate it 90 deggres.

Photo1
[this is how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq9sz.png)
Photo2
[this is how i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkrMO.png)

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tile2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tile_player_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tile_enemy_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
     </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

here is java

```
    tiles[2].setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("tile_lava", "drawable", getPackageName()));
    tiles[0].setRotation(90);
```

when i rotate it i recieve spaces between them

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below to the *Imageviews* in layout.xml that aren't fitted to the tile.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Edit

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_player_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_enemy_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is unnecessary and it breaks your design. Remove it.
If your images are not 1x1 ratio, than add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for avoiding white blanks.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_player_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_enemy_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Portrait Mode]
[image: Landscape Mode]

Comment: hi, without relative layout it gives me an error, because i use weigth